# How to connect Angular to PostgresSQL?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular, frontend

I use Angular and want to retrieve data from PostgresSQL, but I don't know where to store the database credentials correctly and how to connect Angular to PostgresSQL.

Do I need a Asp.net or Node.js backened and, if yes, what would it be like to retrieve data from database and send it to the frontend?

Comment: Yes, you need a backend. You don't want all of your clients to have access to the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This logic should contains on backend side.

If you don't have a server side at the moment, then this is also not a problem. In this case, you can use the stub for development purposes. You can use a package like [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) for this.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is that the credentials be stored in a separate .env file inside your backend(maybe node.js or asp.net). This way you wont have the issue of encapsulating the data from the client and they wont get leaked.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What format should the *.env* file use? Key-value? Add an example in your answer.